MongoDB Aggregation to calculate total revenue by each store for each month
I have a collection named sales with documents structured as follows:-
{

"_id": ObjectId("..."),

"date": ISODate("2024-06-15T00:00:00Z"),

"store": "Store A",

"items": [

     {

         "name": "item1",

         "quantity": 5,

         "price": 10.0

     },

     {

         "name": "item2",

         "quantity": 3,

         "price": 20.0

     }

]
}

How do i calculate the total revenue generated by each store for each month, along with the average price of items sold. The result should be sorted first by store and then by month (in ascending order).
Expected Output:-
[

{

     "store": "Store A",

     "month": "2024-06",

     "totalRevenue": 230.0,

     "averagePrice": 15.0

},

{

     "store": "Store B",

     "month": "2024-06",

     "totalRevenue": 150.0,

     "averagePrice": 12.5

}

]

what i've tried:-
db.sales.aggregate([{
  "$group": {
    "_id" : null,
    "totalRevenue": {
      "$sum": {
        "$multiply": ["$quantity", "$price"]
      }
    },
  }
}]);

update:-
db.sales.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      date: { $gte: new ISODate("2024-06-01"), $lt: new ISODate("2024-06-30") },
    },
  },

  {
    $group: {
      month: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } },
      totalRevenue: { $sum: { $multiply: ["$price", "$quantity"] } },
      averagePrice: { $avg: "$price" },
    },
  },

  {
    $sort: { totalRevenue: -1 },
  },
]);


Change your grouping condition. The _id part shouldn't be null as that puts everything in a single bucket

Thanks.. what about filtering the data by month, diff stores?

Why do you group by months when you filter data of one month only.

If you want to group by both month and store, include both of them in the _id value for the $group.
